# Has font rendering improved in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have been reluctant to spend much time learning Silverlight due to what I think is one of its main shortcomings: font rendering. Fonts look absolutely horrible especially at small font sizes and I think it makes it completely useless for any serious (business) application. I have noticed developers tend to cover this up by using light font colours on a dark background.

I have seen many complaints on forums and mentioned this to a Microsoft employee. He replied this is common complaint which will be addressed in Silverlight 3. Others report that although ClearType fonts are supported in SL 3 the font problem is more fundamental and not likely to be resolved any time soon.

Now that SL 3 has been released, has anyone doing active SL development noticed a marked improvement over previous versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a huge improvement over Silverlight 2.  Text that was previously borderline unreadable looks great.  The ClearType rendering works on in all browsers/OSes so this is an across the board improvement.

Comment: Im going to accept your answer; as a minor point I would say it is a significant rather than huge improvement and it looks much better rather than great :). I found this useful comparison:    
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/07/silverlight-v3-cleartype-font-rendering-a-comparison/

Answer (score 3):

Check out Tim Heuer's post [Silverlight 3 Released! What is new/changed?](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-released-what-is-new-and-changed.aspx) where he states:

> ***Improved text rendering:***  The team made large investments in
>   improving the overall rendering of
>   text in Silverlight applications. 
>   Improved text rendering is available
>   to all supported platforms. 
>   Improvements for text animation have
>   also been introduced.

Also, from the official [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/default.aspx) site:

> ***Improved text rendering & font support:*** Silverlight 3 allows far
>   more efficient rendering and rapid
>   animation of text. Applications also
>   load faster by enabling the use of
>   local fonts.

To my untrained eye fonts *do* seem crisper, but I'm no expert.

With regard to ClearType, Tim [says](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx):

> *While not in the beta, we will be adding ClearType support for text
>   rendering in the final version of
>   Silverlight 3.*

I haven't been able to corroborate if it truly made it into the final release.

Comment: Unfortunately your quotes don't say anything about rendering quality, especially about ClearType-like rendering.

Comment: post updated. ClearType was "supposed" to make it into the final release.

Comment: The Silverlight 3 ClearType seems not to be the same as Windows Vista ClearType. It still seems to ignore grid-fitting, which is (in my opinion) vital to ClearType text rendering quality. Note that I don't _know_ about how it is in Silverlight 3, it's just from my testing I described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested a few apps on silverlight.net, some with dark text on white background, including [this one](http://sphinx4.webhop.net/Silver/). It's good, though it still does not fit into the pixel grid everywhere, like ClearType does. It's good enough though, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that it has improved quite a bit. Have a look at the following comparison:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/wpf/2009/07/silverlight-v3-cleartype-font-rendering-a-comparison/

Previously SL used the same rendering technique as WPF, simple anti-aliasing. However, now SL3 has ClearType support, where fonts are smoothed using sub-pixel anti-aliasing.

But ... this is only applied if the user has ClearType enabled. AFAIK, this is off by default on Windows XP. So if possible, check with your users first!

Still not as good as WinForms, especially when rendering bold text.

Colin E.